# css-styled search form input field looks terrible in IE7

Tags: html, css, forms, input

Here is the screenshot of my web-development:

[Screenshot http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/2668/searchin.jpg](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/2668/searchin.jpg)

the code: http://jsfiddle.net/pwDXj/5/

The div around the input field is for niftycube, so that the corners are rounded. I cant find out, why IE shows the input-field with this much left margin, anyone got an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything looks terrible in IE7

Comment: What's with that DIV? Why don't you put the INPUT inside the LABEL?

Comment: ...or even next to the label as it is and just eliminate the DIV

Comment: Also, if the name of the FORM is "suche", then its ID should also be "suche". The DIV wrapper should have an ID like "suche-wrap"...

Comment: the div around the input field is for niftycube, so that the corners are rounded - in the screenshot you can see the rounded corners

Comment: @roeb Where do yo define that magnifying glass? I don't see it in the CSS ...

Comment: the lense has nothing to do with the problem ... ... the screenshot is from my local development ... i cant upload niftycube.js or the picture for the lense to jsfiddle, so the lense is only local visible to me ... (#suche input
{background: url('/img/lupe_suche.png') no-repeat right #eff5fc;)}

Comment: Why were the first three comments flagged? Is there anything noisy, offensive or spammy about them that I haven't noticed?

Comment: the first comment isn't helping in any way - the following two are noisy in a way of distracting from an approach to find a solution, apparently they didn't read the question to the end ... even the fourth comment has nothing to do with the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offending code seems to be the `left-margin` of `50px` on `#suche #bginput`. IE7 doesn't render this the same as the other browsers. Where they calculate the margin from the left of the containing element, IE7 is calculating it from the right side of the thing that's floated to the left.

I would suggest floating `#suche #bginput` to the right and not setting the `left-margin`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it may get you pointed in the right direction.
You probabaly have to setup some special CSS for IE7.
You can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

replace this css

## suche

{
    width:  220px;
    height: 30px;
    position:  absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom:  0px;
    background-color:  #cbddf1;
}
 #suche  form
{
    margin:  0px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
}
 #suche label
{
      color: #003399;
    float: left;
    font-size:  0.85em;
    line-height:  24px;
    padding-right:  10px;
}
 #suche #bginput
{
     background-color:  #EFF5FC;
    float: left;
    height:  18px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 150px;
}
 #suche input
{
    margin: 0px;
    border:0px;
    color:  #003399;
    font-size:  0.7em;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #eff5fc;
    }